# SQL Azure query aggregate performance issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql, azure

I'm trying to improve our SQL Azure database performamce, trying to change the use of CURSOR while this is (as everybody told me) something to avoid.

Our table is about GPS information, rows with a id clustered index and secondary indexes on device, timestamp and geography index on location.

I'm trying to compute some statistic such minimum speed (doppler and computed), total distance, average speed, ... along period for a specific device.

I have NO choice on the stat and CAN'T change the table or output because of production.

I have a clear performance issue when running this inline tbl function on my SQL Azure DB.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_logMetrics_3] 
(   
    @p_device smallint, 
    @p_from dateTime,
    @p_to   dateTime,
    @p_moveThresold int = 1
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
    RETURN 
    (
         WITH CTE AS
         (
            SELECT  
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY timestamp) AS RowNum,
                Timestamp,
                Location,
                Alt,
                Speed
            FROM 
                LogEvents
            WHERE 
                Device = @p_device 
                AND Timestamp >= @p_from 
                AND Timestamp <= @p_to),
        CTE1 AS
        (
            SELECT 
                t1.Speed as Speed,
                t1.Alt as Alt,
                t2.Alt - t1.Alt as DeltaElevation,
                t1.Timestamp as Time0,
                t2.Timestamp as Time1,
                DATEDIFF(second, t2.Timestamp, t1.Timestamp) as Duration,
                t1.Location.STDistance(t2.Location) as Distance
            FROM 
                CTE t1
            INNER JOIN 
                CTE t2 ON t1.RowNum = t2.RowNum + 1),
        CTE2 AS
        (
            SELECT 
                Speed, Alt,
                DeltaElevation,
                Time0, Time1,
                Duration,
                Distance,
                CASE 
                   WHEN Duration <> 0
                      THEN (Distance / Duration) * 3.6 
                      ELSE NULL 
                END AS CSpeed,
                CASE 
                   WHEN DeltaElevation > 0 
                      THEN DeltaElevation 
                      ELSE NULL 
                END As PositiveAscent,
                CASE
                   WHEN DeltaElevation < 0 
                      THEN DeltaElevation 
                      ELSE NULL 
                END As NegativeAscent,
                CASE 
                   WHEN Distance < @p_moveThresold 
                      THEN Duration 
                      ELSE NULL 
                END As StopTime,
                CASE 
                   WHEN Distance > @p_moveThresold 
                      THEN Duration 
                      ELSE NULL 
                END As MoveTime
            FROM 
                CTE1 t1
    )
    SELECT
        COUNT(*) as Count,
        MIN(Speed) as HSpeedMin, MAX(Speed) as HSpeedMax, 
        AVG(Speed) as HSpeedAverage,
        MIN(CSpeed) as CHSpeedMin, MAX(CSpeed) as CHSpeedMax, 
        AVG(CSpeed) as CHSpeedAverage,
        SUM(Distance) as CumulativeDistance, 
        MAX(Alt) as AltMin, MIN(Alt) as AltMax,
        SUM(PositiveAscent) as PositiveAscent,
        SUM(NegativeAscent) as NegativeAscent,
        SUM(StopTime) as StopTime,
        SUM(MoveTime) as MoveTime
    FROM 
        CTE2 t1
)
```

The broad idea is

- CTE is selecting the correponding rows, following the parameters
- CTE1 perform aggregation within two consecutive row, in order to get Duration and Distance
- then CTE2 perform operation on these Distance and Duration
- Finally the last select is doing aggregation such sum and average over each columns

Everything working pretty well, until the last SELECT call where the agregate function (which are only few sum and average) killed the performance.

This query selecting 1500 rows against table with 4M rows is taking 1500ms.

when replacing the last select with

```
SELECT ÇOUNT(*) as count FROM CTE2 t1
```

then it's take only few ms.. (down to 2ms according to SQL Studio statistics).

with

```
   SELECT
   COUNT(*) as Count,
   SUM(MoveTime) as MoveTime
```

it's about 125ms

with

```
   SELECT
   COUNT(*) as Count,
   SUM(StopTime) as StopTime,
   SUM(MoveTime) as MoveTime
```

it's about 250ms

like each aggregate are running on consecutive loop operation over all the row, within the same thread and without beeing parallelized

For information, the CURSOR version (I wrote couple of year ago) of this function is running actually at least twice fast...

What is wrong with this aggregate? How to optimize it?

**UPDATE :**

[The query plans for 
SELECT COUNT(*) as Count](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIxaE.jpg)

[The query plans for the full Select with agregate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A69Ue.jpg)

According the answer of Joe C, I introduce a #tmp table in the plans and perform the aggregate on it. The result is about twice as fast, which is an interesting fact.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post query plans for each of the queries mentioned.

Comment: One thing I would try is to run Select * From Cte2 into #Temp and then run the aggregate query against the temp table.  I am curious to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Joe C: This is interesting, the gain is about three time faster. But still more than the Cursor version.. And about query Plans, honestly i never use it before and it's a bit difficult for me to analyse..

Comment: If you can right click on the execution plan and show as XML, that will be more useful than the image.  Also if you could script your table -> create table to show the table definition, that would be helpful as well.  It appears you are only accessing one table, correct?  How often is data inserted, deleted and updated?  Something like an indexed view might be the right way to go depending on how often data is written.

Comment: On a side note I do not see any parallel processing in the plans.  Are you using SQL on azure VM or SQL Azure.  Maybe check out this article - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-compatibility-level-query-performance-130/

Comment: I use SQL Azure.  One table, Insert data hundred time by seconds and also readed often. To be honnest the design is very poor, while this is a work done for a Proof of Concept and we do not change it after all. BTW I was just reading an article about indexed view, but actually never used and need to understand how to apply here. The XML of the plans are quite big, posting it here will maybe a bad idea..

Comment: Some people here use pastebin to link large text files.  Basically an indexed view will keep the results of your aggregate query persisted and give outstanding performance on reads.  Each write to the table however requires updating the view so its a trade off and depends on how often the data is updated.  Not sure what you mean by insert data hundred time by seconds.

Comment: I finalize read of some tutorial about view, but as far the table as a LOT of insert (100 per seconds) it's seem not compatible with my poor design. English is not my mother language, then it's sometime (often) unclear :-)

Comment: No problem on the language barrier.  In my experience when a dataset us updated often and there are many aggregations going on with reporting a snapshot or data warehouse is the solution of choice.  Is it critical that the data is real time or can you perhaps do a periodic update to a reporting data store?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120813/discussion-between-guillaume-pelletier-and-joe-c).